# python anaconda conda-pack - environment doesn't exist

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-pack

I am trying to migrate my environment to a new machine that does not have internet access using the Anaconda command “conda pack.” However, the command returns that the environment was not found

I am using windows

env list

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\User
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51UPw.png)

comando conda pack

```
$ conda pack -n base
Collecting packages...
CondaPackError: Environment name 'base' doesn't exist
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evgfj.png)

Do you have any ideas on how to make the command work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `conda-pack` is not intended for *base*

The **base** environment is special and doesn't live in the `envs/` folder, where `conda pack` is going to look for an environment to package. Generally, you should not be working with **base** as an environment for redeployment.<sup>**1**</sup> Instead, create a new environment with the packages you wish to bundle and use `conda pack` on that.

### Use `constructor` for custom *base* installers

If you want to create an installer that doesn't assume a **base** installation and will instead create one, then this should be done with [Conda's `constructor` tool](https://github.com/conda/constructor). This is what [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) uses to bundle its custom Conda deployments and provides additional control over configuration settings, not just package installation.

---

<sub>**[1]:** The `conda-pack` tool assumes that an existing Conda installation is present, i.e., there should already be a **base** on the target system. Hence, it wouldn't make sense to deploy a new "base" to the system - either overwriting the existing one, or creating an new environment with `conda` installed. One should only have `conda` installed in **base**.</sub>